# Get the highest/lowest value from 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got this table:

```
  BP1             BP2
 -----------------------------
 140              80
 153              88
 90               162
 98               214
 98               69
```

I want to organize it into 2 columns: one of high BP and other of low BP:

Expected output:

```
BP_High        BP_Low
---------------------------------
140             80
153             88
162             90
214             98
98              69
```

*all values are int

I've tried:

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN BP1 > BP2 THEN BP1
             WHEN BP1 < BP2 THEN BP2 END BP_High,
        CASE WHEN BP1 > BP2 THEN BP2
             WHEN BP1 < BP2 THEN BP1 END BP_Low 
FROM Table
```

and it does not work...it gives me all mixed up:

```
BP_High        BP_Low
---------------------------------
140             80
153             88
90             162
98             214
98              69
```

I've also tried:

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN BP1 > BP2 THEN BP1
             ELSE BP2 END BP_High,
        CASE WHEN BP1 > BP2 THEN BP2
             ELSE BP1 END BP_Low
 FROM Table
```

Is there any other way then CASE WHEN to in order to get the highest/lowest value from 2 columns?

Comment: are you _sure_ the columns are int and not varchars or similar?

Comment: it appears the code works as you want it to, so there's something missing from your question that's causing it to behave differently for you: https://dbfiddle.uk/5QDjTpjy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your third attempt is almost correct, and you in fact can use `CASE` expressions here:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN BP1 > BP2 THEN BP1 ELSE BP2 END AS BP_High,
    CASE WHEN BP1 < BP2 THEN BP1 ELSE BP2 END AS BP_Low
FROM yourTable;
```

On other databases, such as MySQL, Postgres, or SQLite, there are `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` scalar functions available.  On those databases, your query can be simplified to:

```sql
SELECT
    GREATEST(BP1, BP2) AS BP_High,
    LEAST(BP1, BP2) AS BP_Low
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: SQL Server 2022 [supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-2022?view=sql-server-ver16#language) both functions.

Comment: @Zhorov Well it's about time...hopefully they introduce some better regex support as well `:-)`